# Does TP-Link TD-W8968 has print support for ubuntu

Tags: printing

TP-Link TD-W8968 advertises print server support for Win and Mac OS. Does it support printing with Ubuntu OS?

Answer (score -1):

No, it does not support linux distribution for print server.

Ps. I have one of this and i run ubuntu.

Comment: Is there any proof? Print servers are OS independent.

Comment: Print servers are os independent. I do not disagree on that but the protocol used by TP-Link W8968 requires a special software which run on windows and mac only.  Check this [link](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/download/TD-W8968.html#Utility)

Comment: That may just be the remote controller software for the print server. Many hardware manufacturers bundle more or less useless software with their products even though they run on standard protocols.